# msAccess query with Sum and extra criteria

Tags: ms-access

I need to get all of the Costs values for a Dog in a specific month. When I use this code with Access it says the join operation is not supported. Is there a better way to accomplish this in MS Access? I need all of the dog names to come back even if they don't have a cost associated with them for a specific month

```
Select Dog.DogName, Dog.DogOwner, Sum(Costs.CostAmount)
From 
(Dog Left join Costs on Dog.DogName = Costs.DogName and Costs.CostMonth = 10)
Group by Dog.DogName, Dog.OwnerName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  Dogs.DogName
        , Dogs.OwnerName
        , (
            SELECT  SUM(Costs.CostAmountAmount) 
            FROM    Costs 
            WHERE   Dogs.DogName = Costs.DogName AND 
                    Costs.CostMonth =NumMonth
          )
FROM Dogs;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select 
    Dog.DogName, Dog.DogOwner, Sum(Costs.CostAmount) As TotalAmount
From 
    Dog 
Left join 
    Costs 
    On 
       (Dog.DogName = Costs.DogName) 
Where
    Costs.CostMonth <= Month(Date())
    Or
    Costs.CostMonth Is Null
Group by 
    Dog.DogName, Dog.OwnerName
```

Comment: I have used that but it nullifies the left join, I need all the dogs to come back.

Comment: so I ran into a problem with this, if the horse has a month 9 cost then they won't show up, is there a way around that or do I need to restructure my tables?

Comment: If other months than _10_ or none (_Null_) are to be listed, adjust the Where clause accordingly.

Comment: I don't think you are fully understanding what I am saying. The Cost Table will have Cost for each month as separate entries. so, for example, a dog might come in September and get some work and Might not come again in October. If I am doing this roll-up for October I want to see that he is still on the dogs table even if he didn't come in September yet. with the way we currently have it, he won't show because he doesn't have any October costs but his costs are also not null. The where is only for the SUM really, I only want the monthly expenses to have the Costs that were accrued in that mont

Comment: Well, originally you asked: _I need to get all of the Costs values for a Dog in a specific month_ and wrote 10. Anyway, I've edited the answer to take all month. However, you'll need additional steps to not mix up years.

Comment: I do need the costs for a all dogs in a specific month, but I also need to see ALL the dogs, whether they have costs in 9 month or if they have no entries on the table at all but I only want to sum their costs for the given month

Comment: That was what my first answer did - for month 10.

Comment: Yea it was for month 10 or if it was null, but if the dog had an expense in 9 it wouldn't be returned because the month was not 10 or null, so It was not giving me all the dognames from the dog tables, only the ones that didn't have any expenses in any other month.